# JQuery bind + bootstrap doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem, I want to do some action if user change data in my input, but unfortunately code doesnt work. I use Bootstrap + jQuery

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
<input type="text" id="input_val" name="input_val" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('input_val', '1'); ?>">
</div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
$('#input_val').bind('input', function(){
  console.log('this actually works');
});
```

Comment: What does not work there? See http://jsfiddle.net/brainbolt/52VtD/4/  ... but I'm not sure what `echo set_value('input_val', '1');` outputs, do you have a `vardump()` for that?

Comment: Its Codeigniter function for input default value (1) if form wasn't submited, or last value if it was submited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for help, (I use Bootstrap/jQuery/Codeigniter if that will help somebody) but  if I add $( document ).ready my script is working. Thanks for all anyway :)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
...myscript...
});
```

Comment: With newer versions of jQuery, you can shorten that to `$(function() { ...myscript... });`

Answer (score 0):

it worked to me:
http://jsbin.com/bifuwiyugo/1/edit?html,js,output

check it out:

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$( "#input_va" ).change(function() {
    console.log('this actually works');
});
```